# Reading UTF8 files with File::Slurp

Tags: perl, encoding, fileslurp

I try to read an HTML file with the Perl module [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp):

```
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
my $htmlcontent = read_file($file, {binmode => ':utf8'});
```

But when I print the `$htmlcontent` variable, some characters are not understood, due to French accents or special characters.

For example : `"Plus d'actualit\u00e9s"` should be `"Plus d'actualités"`

I also checked the encoding of the file and it's ok!

```
HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

Is there a problem with this module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`\u00e9` is not an UTF-8 character, is JavaScript represent of Unicode character. You need decode content of file with [Encode::JavaScript::UCS](http://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::JavaScript::UCS) for example.

Comment: I tried your solution but still the same problem.
I've tested on another machine and the problem disappeared. I think it is a problem of OS environment.